# Javascript micro library for user accounts, OAuth, OpenID?

Tags: javascript, oauth, openid

http://microjs.com/ doesn't seem to list anything related to this, and my google searches come up dry too.

I am looking for ANY client-side or server-side javascript library that just handles most of the user account lifecycle (signup, login, forgot password, permissions, etc), and integrates seamlessly with OAuth and OpenID...not part of a monolithic framework.

Any hints?